# Allow Users of the Same roles the Ability to Delete edit Each Other’s Records drupal

Tags: drupal-8

I have two roles

```
Group a 
Group B
```

And Group a have two users namely `user1,user 2`
similarly Group b have two users namely `user3,user 4`

Is there any group wise permission allowed in drupal? If user1 a add something user 2 can edit and delete it but not user 3. Similarly for User 3 and user 4. Because user 1 and 2 are same role  similarly for user 3 and user 4

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: try this link https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-12-18/how-to-assign-permissions-for-specific-user-groups-for